# unsatisfied link error on android when using STL in natives (NDK) while using standalone toolchain

Tags: stl, android-ndk

I am getting unsatisfied link error when I'm trying to launch my C++ based app on Android. The problem only appear if I use any of STL mechanism, when I comment out all `std::vector` etc. the problem disappears.

EDIT: I found out that this is about all C++, not only STL (ie. `new operator` also cause unsatisfied link error)

I am using custom, standalone toolchain to build binary (targeting android 1.6), and link it with `libstdc++.a`, `libGLESv1_CM.a`, `liblog.a` and `libm.a`.

In Java I call:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("GLESv1_CM");
    System.loadLibrary("Game");
}
```

The exact build order is:

```
engine_sources -> libengine.a

game_sources + libengine.a + all mentioned libraries (using --whole-archive for each) -> libGame.so

Java_framework + libGame.so -> Game.apk
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Edit2:
As suggested in http://mpigulski.blogspot.com/2010/09/debugging-dlopen-unsatisfiedlinkerror.html I run `arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe libGame.so` and got this:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-ld.exe: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00008270
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fadd'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmpgt'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_dmul'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_d2f'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `vtable for OpenGLRenderer'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fsub'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_idiv'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fdiv'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_uidiv'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmpeq'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fmul'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmplt'
libGame.so: undefined reference to `__aeabi_f2d'
```

I am especially concerned about

```
libGame.so: undefined reference to `vtable for OpenGLRenderer'
```

`OpenGLRenderer` is a child of abstract class which I am creating with `new`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly missed `libsupc++.a`. It is required for rtti and exceptions. You should explicitly disable rtti and exceptions (`-fno-rtti -fno-exceptions`) or link against this library.

Comment: I've run a search, there is no libsupc++.a file in toolchain directory. I added both commands to g++ command line (for both engine sources and game sources) and it didn't helped.

Comment: Are you using toolchain extracted from NDK r7? Google has a bug in the script `make-standalone-toolchain.sh` and `libsupc++.a` is not copied to the toolchain automatically (NDK r5 and r6 has no such problem). Try to search for it inside the NDK.

Comment: Where under NDK r7 should libsupc++.a exist?  I am having a similar problem using the stand-alone toolchain.  But, a simple find command didn't do the trick.  Do you have any more details about this bug?

Answer (score 3):

In case people are looking for libsupc++.a, you can find it under:

```
./sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/
```

This is also where you will find libgnustl_shared.so
(sorry, can't add comments to the previous answer, not enough rep)